# "null object reference" when trying to stop a service

Tags: java, android

I would like to stop a service but get this error:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.content.Context.stopService(android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference

This is my method (in class `public class Dialog extends AppCompatActivity`) to stop the service:

```java
public void stopService(Context context) {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, PicovoiceService.class);
    stopService(serviceIntent);
}
```

This is how I invoke that method in another class:

```java
@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class Popup extends DialogFragment {
    private final int _layout;
    private final Dialog mDialog = new Dialog();
    public boolean dialogIsActive = false;

    @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
    public Popup(int layout) {
        _layout = layout;
    } 

    @SuppressLint({"ClickableViewAccessibility", "ResourceType"})
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view =  inflater.inflate(_layout, container, false);

        // Display fragment_dialog
        if (_layout == R.layout.fragment_dialog) {

            // Toggle the listener
            view.findViewById(R.id.dialogCta).setOnClickListener(v -> {
                if (!dialogIsActive) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        if (mDialog.hasRecordPermission(getContext())) {
                            mDialog.startService(getContext());
                            dialogIsActive = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        mDialog.stopService(getContext()); // <-- ERROR
                    }
                    dialogIsActive = false;
                }
            });
        }           
        return view;
    }       
}
```

`mDialog.startService(getContext());` works fine but what's wrong with `mDialog.stopService(getContext());`?

### Update

I have also tried it with `Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), PicovoiceService.class);` and `Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PicovoiceService.class);` but I get the same error.

Comment: try use getApplicationContext()

Comment: @Style-7 I can't use that. I get the error: _Cannot resolve method 'getApplicationContext' in 'Popup'_

Comment: DialogFragment.this

Comment: @Style-7 you mean like this `mDialog.stopService(DialogFragment.this);`? Then I get the error _'android.app.DialogFragment' is not an enclosing class_

Comment: No DialogFragment.this getApplicationContext() or view.getContext().getApplicationContext()

Comment: @Style-7 when trying it with `view.getContext().getApplicationContext()` I get the same error as `getContext()`.

Comment: Looks like service is not running then you try to stop it. Need full code (start etc, and logs.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I could make it work:

```java
private Intent mServiceIntent = null;

public void startService(Context context) {
    mServiceIntent = new Intent(context, PicovoiceService.class);
    ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, mServiceIntent);
}

public void stopTheService(Context context) {
    if (mServiceIntent != null) {
        context.stopService(mServiceIntent);
    }
}
```

The error was gone when I used `context` before `stopService()`.